# After Ubuntu Installation : No Option to choose Ubuntu OS | Always start with Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot

Today I installed Ubuntu alongside windows 8 (option was first, without making partition). Everything was Ok but when the system restart there was no option to choose Ubuntu. By default it always start with my existing OS 8. Please Help me.

Thnx
Lalit Kumar

Comment: If you are using laptop , did windows came pre bundled with it?

Comment: No... but I'm using genuine windows 8.